Legendre Transform understanding
I'm trying to understand the definition of the Legendre transform.
Say I have a function $F(x)$ and I define $s=dF/dx$, and I want to represent the relation between $F(x)$ to $s$, the Legendre Transform is defined by:
$G(s) = sx(s) - F(x(s))$
What I'm failing to understand is why can't I just set:
$G(s)=F(x(s))$
As I understand from what I read in some resources,
the Legendre Transform retains some "information" that $F(x)$ holds,
and that when defining $G(s)=F(x(s))$ I'm losing that information.
What do they mean by this "information"? Can you give an example?
One of the resources that I read:
https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/zia.pdf
Sections I,II,III

First of all: congratulations that you read the best pedagogical paper on the Legendre transform that I can think of. We could probably just set $G(s)=F(x(s))$ and thereby loose the property that the Legendre transform is inverse to itself. Please try that.

Thank you for the comment, I think I'm starting to get it, please correct me if I'm wrong:
If we set G(s)=F(x(s)) we can still get the same "information" as F(x), but with the definition of Legendre Transform we get additional beneficial properties such as the invertibility. Right?

The orthodox definition $G(s)=sx(s)-F(x(s))$ has nice algebraic properties such as being invertible to itself. This comes essentially from $$
\frac{dG}{ds}=x(s)+sx'(x)-\underbrace{\frac{dF}{dx}(x(s))}_{\textstyle s},x'(s)=x(s)
$$ which is the correspondence of $$\frac{dF}{dx}=s(x),.$$ In other words: $x$ and $s$ are conjugate variables to each other.
